# Can't get "retry" to work in Celery

Tags: python, celery, celeryd

Given a file `myapp.py`

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery("myapp")
celery.config_from_object("celeryconfig")

@celery.task(default_retry_delay=5 * 60, max_retries=12)
def add(a, b):
      with open("try.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write("A trial = {}!\n".format(a + b))
      raise add.retry([a, b])
```

Configured with a `celeryconfig.py`

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ["myapp"]
BROKER_URL = "amqp://"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
```

I call in the directory that have both files:

```
$ celeryd -E
```

And then

```
$ python -c "import myapp; myapp.add.delay(2, 5)"
```

or

```
$ celery call myapp.add --args="[2, 5]"
```

So the `try.txt` is created with

```
A trial = 7!
```

only once.
That means, the retry was ignored.

I tried many other things:

- Using MongoDB as broker and backend and inspecting the database (strangely enough, I can't see anything in my broker "messages" collection even in a "countdown"-scheduled job)
- The PING example in [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.amqp.celery.user/3745), both with RabbitMQ and MongoDB
- Printing on the screen with both `print` (like the PING example) and `logging`
- Make the retry call in an except block after an enforced `Exception` is raised, raising or returning the retry(), changing the "throw" parameter to `True`/`False`/not specified.
- Seeing what's happening with `celery flower` (in which the "broker" link shows nothing)

But none happened to work =/

My `celery report` output:

```
software -> celery:3.0.19 (Chiastic Slide) kombu:2.5.10 py:2.7.3
            billiard:2.7.3.28 py-amqp:N/A
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:amqp
```

Is there anything wrong above? What I need to do to make the retry() method work?